# What's the best place to put additional non-XML files within the Module file structure?

Tags: magento

I did a bit of searching and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440682/magento-module-correct-place-to-put-additional-files) on the topic but it's specific to XML files, and so the answer makes sense (/etc/) for XML files.

In  my case, I'm actually storing a txt file, which happens to be an SVN version number that I dumped out within my modman script.

The place that I'm using this is within a frontend model (Blocks/System/Html.php) which outputs the version number within the module config.  So I went with the Blocks/System/ directory for now - the filename is Version.txt - but it feels like there should be a better place to put this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same kind of problem when developing a shipping module.  I had a bunch of CSV files that contained maximum weight / delivery cost mappings.  For what it's worth, I created a `data/` directory at the module level and threw everything in there.

I don't think this kind of situation doesn't happens often enough in the Magento codebase for there to be an established convention.  As long as you use sensible naming, and provide a level of abstraction to cope with any change of file location in the future, I'd say put it in any folder at your module's root.

Comment: Thanks Nick!  I think data/ is the best idea so far.  I actually did notice some core mods with a data/ directory, such as Mage/Admin, but it seemed to be related to setup resources in some way - see Mage/Admin/data/admin_setup/ - is that like an old structure prior to the sql/ directory maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Since this SVN version number is being written by an external tool I would prefer it not mess with the contents of code directories (which in a live environment may have write restrictions) and instead have it write to the "var" directory. In which case to get the correct path within "var" you would use:

```
$fullpath = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . $path;
```

The contents of "var" are disposable, they may be deleted at any time so be prepared for a missing file.

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek!  I sort of like the idea of var/ because the Version.txt file is sort of fundamentally transient since, as you mentioned, it's generated by an external tool and it's basically overwritten every time the mod is deployed or svn-up'd.  But at the same time, I don't necessarily want it to be able to be overwritten at any time, like for example if I'm in a crazy troubleshooting situation with it in the wild, it may be very important to make sure I know the exact version they're using.

Comment: It doesn't have to be "var" of course, take a look at the `<filesystem>` section of `app/etc/config.xml` to see all the usual places that `getBaseDir()` can expect to handle. Or use the root dir directly.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Usually *var* folders are also in .gitignore file. So you'll not have any issues with changed file on your git. Also, you can create something like: *var/yourmodule/* and store everything there. I see geoip and report modules does it actually.

Answer (score 2):

version numbers can be added to `app/code/local/Your/Extension/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Extension>
            <version>0.0.0.0</version>
        </Your_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

magento knows how to handle your extension version changes and can call update scripts based on version number change. This is the preferred method for this kind of stuff.

if you need to add random non php classes files to your extension then add them to your extension folder and ask them from there:

```
Mage::getModuleDir('etc', 'Your_Extension');
Mage::getModuleDir('whateverfolder', 'Your_Extension');
```

This is not a good practice though as this might just break magento compilation feature or introduce other issues so it is better to handle external data also through php classes or xml files inside your extension structure

Comment: And of course the way to get that version number from XML is `Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/Your_Extension/version')`

Comment: Thanks Anton!  So I did think about maybe dynamically rewriting the config.xml to drop the SVN revision number in there but since config.xml is versioned that would force me to then commit that change to the file, which would cause a lot of cruft.  Wasn't sure if there was a good way around that?

Comment: same scenario for your other file or this is not versioned?